# How can I provide a bounty after the fact?

Tags: support, bounties

For some answers that really help me or go "above and beyond," I'd like to transfer some of my points to the helpful/heroic answerer. How can this be done? All I see at the answer check is an option to un-mark the answer as THE answer, and otherwise to share, edit, or flag it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `start a bounty` button below the `add comment` button.

[image]

Comment: No, there isn't - maybe the required time period dafuer has not yet elapsed.